# php compare times

Tags: php, datetime

I have the php code below comparing two times against the current time using strtotime:

```
 $timingsfirstTime[0] = date("H:i:s", strtotime(trim($showTimings[0])));
 $timingslastTime[2] = date("H:i:s", strtotime(trim($showTimings[2])));
```

// Confirm that the start time of the frist show is greater than the last time of last show on the channel

```
        $current_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime('now'));

        $this->assertTrue(($current_time > $timingsfirstTime[0] && $current_time < $timingslastTime[2]),"current time ".$current_time. " is not greater than current show start time ". $timingsfirstTime[0] . " or current time is not less than current show end time ".$timingslastTime[2]);
```

But my the assertion fails somehow and outputs:

current time 00:38:45 is not greater than current show start time 23:50:00 or current time is not less than current show end time 00:50:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing string comparisons, not date comparisons, which is why it's "failing".

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead, since it's easier to read, less code, and can be compared natively.  I would also split your assertion into two assertions to make it easier to tell what case failed:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$start = new DateTime($showTimings[0]);
$end = new DateTime($showTimings[2]);

$this->assertTrue(
    $now > $start,
    'current time ' . $now->format('H:i:s')
        . ' is not greater than current show start time '
        . $start->format('H:i:s')
);

$this->assertTrue(
    $now < $end,
    'current time ' . $now->format('H:i:s')
        . ' is not less than current show end time '
        . $end->format('H:i:s')
);
```

Comment: String comparisons in VB don't carry over to PHP

Comment: @ColeJohnson: What are you talking about?  Sorry, I don't know VB.

Comment: i thought i was using the date function to wrap the times

Comment: In VB.NET, you can do this: `"2011-01-01 12:00" < DateTime.Now`

Comment: @van the date function returns an integer representing the number of seconds from the unix epoch. The man page for date would have told you that

Comment: @ColeJohnson:  The [`date()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function returns a string, not an integer.  The man page for `date()` would have told you that.  ;-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn oh duh. I was thinking of mktime and time.

Comment: Those string comparisons are perfectly valid given that they use leading zeros on the times. The problem is that there's no date involved so 11pm last night is "greater than" 1am this morning. Using `DateTime` obviously solves that neatly. :)

Comment: @DavidHarkness: It's never a good idea to compare dates or times as strings.  It makes for very brittle code (easy to break).  It also depends on one of the very few formats which actually sort properly (e.g. "Y-m-d H:i:s" or variants thereof), and this is most often not the format you want to be showing your users anyway, so it just makes more sense to always use `DateTime`.

Comment: @drrcknlsn - No argument here (though I would hesitate to say *never*). I only noted that the string comparison itself wasn't failing due to some special effect of time formats. It was caused by comparing the times without the dates.